# Problems about ListActivity, cursor and SQL data update

Tags: java, android, sql

currently I am using ListActivity. I use a cursor to get the data from SQL, and built the ListView according to the SQL query result. For every objects in my ListView, if I press that object (onListItemClick), it will change the value in the SQL that the cursor will read, and open a new intent.(Pressing on different object will change different value in the SQL table). To keep my ListView most updated, I use

```
//adapter is the SimpleCursorAdapter I use
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);
    //change the data in sql
    ...
    //change the data end
    adapter.changeCursor(dbAdapter.getResult(id));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //create intent here
    //startActivity(intent)
}
```

The problem is, if I keep pressing the same object, leave the intent it create, it works fine. But once I press a different object after I leave the previous intent, my ListView becomes empty. For example, if I press object a, I enter intent a, and then I leave intent a, back to List View (ListView is fine now), then I press on object b, I enter the intent b. When I leave intent b, the ListView becomes empty. Does anyone has any idea about this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like some of your data is being destroyed.  I think if you move your list creation code to onResume, your problem will solve itself as the list will be re-generated every time you come back, wheras in onCreate it is only done when the activity is first created.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Comment: OMG it works! previously I just try to move the update function to onresume, now I make whole list generating stuff there, and it just works! Thanks a lot!